# Swift: how to replace a completion handler with a Future in an element initializer?

Tags: swift, future, combine

I am sorry if this sounds very beginner, but after looking at Apple doc as well as several tutorials I still struggle to understand how Combine's Future works.

I have this very simple code which stores the current date on first button tap, and prints the interval on the second one:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var startTime: Date = .now
    private var completion: (TimeInterval) -> Void = { _ in }
    private var isOn = false
    
    @IBAction func tapped() {
        if isOn {
            completion(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))
        } else {
            startTime = .now
        }
        isOn.toggle()
    }

    init(_ completion: @escaping (TimeInterval) -> Void) {
        super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: .main)
        self.completion = completion
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

In my AppDelegate:

```
window?.rootViewController = MyViewController {
    print("Tapped with time interval: \($0)")
}
```

Now I would like to replace that completion handler with a `Future`, but I'm confused about what to do. I guess I have to create a function like this in my view controller:

```
func afterSecondTap() -> Future<TimeInterval, Error> {
    return Future { promise in
        // what to do here?
    }
}
```

And in the `AppDelegate` something like this:

```
window?.rootViewController = MyViewController()
    .afterSecondTap()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            
    }, receiveValue: { value in
            
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

However this would not work because I get an error saying

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'UIViewController'

Thank you for helping me understand this

Comment: May be use concurrency instead of Combine's Future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First when you assign a rootViewController it expects UIViewController of some sort, as soon as you add `.afterSecondTap()` and the rest it changes the type. So let's start like this

```
let controller = MyViewController()
window?.rootViewController = controller
```

Next let's see how we can publish time interval from the controller, I would think `Future` is not what you need:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var startTime: Date = .now
    private var isOn = false
    
    var timeInterval: AnyPublisher<TimeInterval, Never> {
        _timeInterval
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    private var _timeInterval = ConcurrentValueSubject<TimeInterval?, Never>(nil)
    
    @IBAction func tapped() {
        if isOn {
            _timeInterval.send(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
        } else {
            startTime = .now
        }
        isOn.toggle()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: .main)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

now you can do this:

```
let controller = MyViewController()
window?.rootViewController = controller
controller
    .timeInterval
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { _ in },
        receiveValue: { _ in })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I now understand how to use it, I will read the doc in order to understand when to use either PassthroughSubject, AnyPublisher or Future.

Comment: No problem. Future is most commonly used when you want to change a closure into a publisher. CurrentValueSubject and PassthroughSubject are for when you want to construct a publisher and then manually send values using it. AnyPublisher is just a type erased publisher also that the call sites don’t have to know about your implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

When you store a `Cancellable` using `.store`, the value returned will no longer be `UIViewController`, it is going to be `Void`.

You shouldn't use `Future`, instead use `PassThroughSubject` like so:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var startTime: Date = .now
    private var isOn = false
    var publisher = PassthroughSubject<TimeInterval, Never>()
    @IBAction func tapped() {
        if isOn {
            publisher.send(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))
        } else {
            startTime = .now
        }
        isOn.toggle()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: .main)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
let viewController = MyViewController()
viewController
    .publisher
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                
        }, receiveValue: { value in
                
        })
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
    .
window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I now understand how to use it, I will read the doc in order to understand when to use either PassthroughSubject, AnyPublisher or Future.